# How to save a sound to Download folder of Internal Memory

Tags: android

I have a soundboard with a number of sounds contained in the Raw folder. Each button corresponds to a sound being played when clicked.

I'd like to long click on a sound and save that .mp3 file to the Download folder of the phone's storage. My phone does not have SD Card capability, so it would be to the Internal Memory only.

I have some code for now, which I have experimented with to try and save a sound to the app's location, but I am not aware of how to change that to relate to Downloads instead.

Is anybody able to help out please? I have attached some of my code below in case it is needed. Many thanks.

```
@Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

            Button a;

            a = findViewById(R.id.button11);

           final String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
                    + "/media/audio/";

            a.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {

                    try {
                        copyRAWtoPhone(R.raw.addressmeassir, path);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    return true;
                }

                private void copyRAWtoPhone(int id, String path) throws IOException {

                    InputStream in = getResources().openRawResource(id);
                    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(path);
                    byte[] buff = new byte[1024];
                    int read = 0;
                    try {
                        while ((read = in.read(buff)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buff, 0, read);
                        }
                    } finally {
                        in.close();
                        out.close();
                    }


                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Saving to `Download` folder:

```
 val file = File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS), name)
  if (writeToFile_1(Objects.requireNonNull<ResponseBody>(response.body()), file)) {
   Toast.makeText(context.applicationContext, "File was downloaded.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
   } else {
   Toast.makeText(context.applicationContext, "Error.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

and file creating:

```
private fun writeToFile_1(body: ResponseBody, file: File): Boolean {
        var inputStream: InputStream? = null
        var outputStream: OutputStream? = null
        try {
            inputStream = body.byteStream()
            outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)

            val buffer = ByteArray(4096)
            while (true) {
                val read = inputStream.read(buffer)
                if (read < 0) break
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, read)
            }
            outputStream.close()
            return true
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } finally {
            if (inputStream != null) {
                try {
                    inputStream.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            }
            if (outputStream != null) {
                try {
                    outputStream.close()
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

I use this method for saving files from server, but you can write some another `byte[]` I hope that you will got the main idea of my method. You have to get `byte[]` of your sound and then write to file via my method. Good luck :)

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your help. I'm afraid to say that it doesn't work for me and I'm not sure I fully understand.

Comment: Hi. Yes, numerous ones. Where do I place your code for file creating? Will I put it within the setonclicklisterner I have set up for my button? Thanks.